# application closing without error - In background 

Tags: android

I've created a simply web radio streaming app, and on of my app user told me that sometimes when he open another app (for example, Facebook app) my app gets close without error.

How can I trace this event?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your app is simply experiencing the standard [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

When the user leaves your app (eg opens the Facebook app), onStop() is called. From there, the app can either be restarted, it can just sit there, or it can be destroyed.

Since the Facebook app is fairly resource-intensive, I am guessing that the system is destroying your app to free up resources for the Facebook app, or whatever other app is being launched.

If you tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish, we can provide more suggestions on how to do that.

Comment: I have supposed your scenario, but my app have the necessity to remaining opened as much as possible, or (if there are a mode) go in pause and restart when resources diminish. Thank you.

Comment: In that case you may want to look at implementing your app (or part of your app) as a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Though Android will try to keep Services running as long as possible, there are still scenarios in which they can be stopped. Those scenarios can be found in the [Process Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle) section of the Services page.